# AngularJS - perform extra validation on form submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, submit

I've been googling for a while and can't seem to find a good answer for my specific case.  I've found ways to do real-time validations but I want to combine that with some custom validations after a user clicks on "submit". I want to allow the user to still click on the submit even if it's not valid but then I'll cancel the submission in the code.  Take the following code:

```
<form name="cashForm" id="cashForm" novalidate>
  <input type="text" id="name" required /> //
  <input type="number" placeholder="Tax: " required name="tax" id="tax" />
  <input type="number" placeholder="Tip: " required name="tip" id="tip" />
  <button ng-click="submission()" ng-disabled="paymentForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>


//inside controller
this.submission = function() {
  //check if tip + tax is over 20
  //prevent form and show error message if not
  //otherwise allow default behavior
}
```

So I only want the form to actually submit if the tax/tip is over 10.  How do I check for this and how do I prevent the form submission if it doesn't meet the requirements?  Also, would I put this logic in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty close to what you're after to me. Just a couple of things...

Add `ng-model` directives to your input controls to create two-way data-bindings that you can pick up and use in your controller:

```
<form name="cashForm" id="cashForm" novalidate>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="nameValue" required />
    <input id="tax" name="tax" type="number" ng-model="taxValue" placeholder="Tax: " required   />
    <input id="tip" name="tip" type="number" ng-model="tipValue" placeholder="Tip: " required />
    <button 
        ng-click="submission()" 
        ng-disabled="paymentForm.$invalid"> 
        Submit 
    </button>
```

Inject `$scope` into your controller to allow you to pick up those `ng-model` bindings in your controller's `submission` method:

```
function submission() {

    $scope.errorMsg = "";

    if ($scope.taxValue <= 10) {
        $scope.errorMsg = "tax not greater than 10";
        return;
    }

    if ($scope.tipValue <= 10) {
        $scope.errorMsg = "tip not greater than 10";
        return;
    }

    // If you reached here your post-click validation passed, 
    // so continue to submit the data...

 }
```

You could then display an error message using the `ng-if` directive with a css class that highlights the error message:

```
<div ng-if="!!errorMessage" class="text-danger">
    {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
```

Finally, once you've cracked using `$scope` in your controller you might want to read about the perceived evils of using `$scope` and consider switching to controller-as syntax instead. Check out John Papa's Blog Post [AngularJS's Controller As and the vm Variable](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I think that should get me to a good point.  One last question, is the controller the correct spot to put this logic?  I've heard that you shouldn't put too much logic in the controller but it seems to be like this is the only spot that makes sense.

Comment: Personally, I think it's fine in the controller because the conditions directly determine what the view model (`$scope`) gets populated with i.e. which error message(s). It's true that you should try to keep the controller as lean as possible, and I do get uncomfortable if I have to do lots of scrolling in a controller, it probably means it's doing too many things. If it gets out of control then consider abstracting all of the "check whether to submit" logic out into a custom directive and create your own custom-click (submit) behavior to replace that of `ng-click` on the button.

Comment: Then if you wanted to get _really_ clever, try making the custom directive reusable by passing in a config object that contains the settings that determine whether a submit is allowed to proceed. Then you can reuse it and replicate the behaviour with comparative ease. An investment of time.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  I will give it a shot and see what I can do.  Btw I am using the "Controller As" so I don't need to pass in a scope.